# Set cloud foundry enviornment variables from udeploy properties

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am using the udeploy cloudfoundry plugin to push applications to cloudfoundry

How can I set the enviornment variables in cloud foundry from udeploy

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables can be set in your [cloud foundry manifest file](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#env-block), `manifest.yml` using the `env:` block. For example:

```
env:
  http_proxy: http://proxy.example.com:8080
applications:
...
```

If the value of the environment variable is dynamic, you can use a token:

```
env:
  http_proxy: @PROXY_SERVER_PORT@
applications:
...
```

And use a "replace tokens in manifest file" step in your [Urban Code deploy flow](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/hickmat/entry/bluemix_and_urbancode_getting_more_adventurous?lang=en).